# firebase permission denied in real device

Tags: android, firebase

I am getting this error:

W/SyncTree: Listen at /Bible/card_6 failed: DatabaseError: Permission denied

I was getting this error, but after factory reset phone, it works perfectly. It is very strange. When it was not working. I was getting this log(D/!!!!mCurrentUser: vWGyqTXKpkReBEIb1BQuG3a1Q843 ). This log is supposed to print out when mCurrentUser is not null according to my code below which means app already create user even after fresh installing my app. I delete anonymous 
 user on firebase authentication console. so I still don't get why firebase still recognize I signed in even if I didn't signed in. I am guessing there is some sort of cookie in my phone that firebase installed to interact with my app because after factory reset my phone. It works perfectly. The error occurs when the code right below hits. Doesn't anyone have some idea on this? Any help would be appreciated.

Realtime database security rule:

```
{
  "rules": { 
    ".read": "auth!=null",
    ".write": "auth!=null"
    }
}
```

```
      databaseReference.child("bibles").orderByChild("likecount").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                bList.clear();
                bList2.clear();
                for (DataSnapshot i : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    Bible b = i.getValue(Bible.class);



                    b.setKey(i.getKey());
                    if (b.getCategory().equals(value)) {
                        if (b.getIsChecked().get(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()) == null) {
                            bList2.add(b);

                            // Log.d("TAG", bList2.toString());
                            continue;
                        }

                        bList.add(b);
                    }
                }
```

```
  mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        mCurrentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();

        if (mCurrentUser == null) {
            Log.d("UserNull", "test");
            mAuth.signInAnonymously().addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Log.d("signIn", "test");
                        if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
                            mInterstitialAd.show();
                            mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onAdClosed() {
                                    //TODO: Intent
                                    //
                                    Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MainActivity.class);
                                    startActivity(intent);


                                }
                            });
                        } else {
                            //TODO: Intent
                            Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MainActivity.class);
                            startActivity(intent);



                        }

                    } else {
                        Log.d("authentication failed", "failed");
                    }
                }
            });
        } else {
            Log.d("!!!!mCurrentUser", String.valueOf(mCurrentUser.getUid()));
            Handler h = new Handler();
            h.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override public void run() {
                    if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
                        mInterstitialAd.show();
                        mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onAdClosed() {
                                //TODO: Intent
                                //
                                Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MainActivity.class);
                                startActivity(intent);


                            }
                        });
                    } else {
                        //TODO: Intent
                        Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MainActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);



                    }

                }
```

Comment: Please edit the question to show the code that isn't working the way you expect.  I don' see any database queries here.  Also, since it's a permission error, that probably has to do with security rules on your database.  Please also edit the question to include the active rules.

Comment: I am sorry I just edited:)

Comment: The error suggests that you're performing the query before the user is fully signed in.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I did auth coding in LoadingActivity. Did I do something wrong in LoadingAcitivity for Authentication?

Comment: It's hard to say precisely wht's going on with the amount of code you shared. I highly recommend reading [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), as it increases the chances someone can help. In the meantime, I recommend checking/logging `FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser()` on a line right before the exception is thrown.

Comment: My app works when I run for the second time not the first time. so I think it has to do with authentication. I must have done something wrong. So I don't know what to do. I did some change on LoadingActivity and post a question on authentication. Here is the link. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61991056/i-have-trouble-writing-code-for-firebase-anonymous-login-in-android

Comment: I made some change and edited the post.

Comment: @DougStevenson, I googled on how to signing in anonymously in firebase but I couldn't find any good resources. Would you recommend any good resources on how to sign in anonymously in firebase?

Comment: @Frank van Puffelen I edited question on the post. would you please look at my question again?